# Pattern for binding commands on a child ViewModel from a parent menu

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro, eventaggregator

I'm creating a WPF MVVM app using Caliburn Micro.  I have a set of buttons in a menu (Ribbon) that live in the view for my shell view model, which is a ScreenConductor.  Based on the currently active Screen view model, I would like to have the ribbon buttons be disabled/enabled if they are available for use with the active Screen, and call actions or commands on the active Screen.

This seems like a common scenario.  Is there a pattern for creating this behavior?

Comment: bind your buttons to a relaycommand inside your viewmodel that sets canexecute based on the current scenario.

Comment: That would create the effect, but I was hoping for something a little more dynamic and less brute force.  Maybe the Screen view model can define what commands it supports, so additional Screens can be added without explicit wiring for each button and Screen in the ScreenConductor view model.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do the reverse thing, instead of checking which commands are supported by the current active screen, let the active screen populate the menu or ribbon tab with all the controls that it supports, (i would let it inject its own user control which might just be a complete menu or a ribbon tab all by itself), this will also enhance the user experience as it will only show the user the controls that he can work with for the current active screen.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Just looking at your question again and I'm thinking that this is much simpler than it looks

The only issue I can see you having is that a lack of a handler (and guard) method on a child VM will mean that buttons that don't have an implementation on the currently active VM will still be enabled.

The default strategy for CM is to try and find a matching method name (after parsing the action text) and if one is not found, to leave the button alone. If you were to customise that behaviour so that the default is for buttons to be disabled, you could easily get it working by just implementing the command buttons in your shell, making sure to set the command target to the active item:

In the shell define your buttons, making sure they have a target that points to the active child VM

```
<Button cal:Message.Attach="Command1" cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding ActiveItem}" />
```

Then just implement the method in your child VM as per usual

```
public void Command1() { }
```

and optionally a CanXX guard

```
public bool CanCommand1 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        if(someCondition) return false; 

        return true; 
    } 
}
```

Assuming you don't get much more complex than this, it should work for you

I'm going to have a quick look at the CM source and see if I can come up with something that works for this

EDIT:

Ok you can customise the `ActionMessage.ApplyAvailabilityEffect` func to get the effect you want - in your bootstrapper.Configure() method (or somewhere at startup) use:

```
        ActionMessage.ApplyAvailabilityEffect = context =>
        {
            var source = context.Source;

            if (ConventionManager.HasBinding(source, UIElement.IsEnabledProperty))
            {
                return source.IsEnabled;
            }

            if (context.CanExecute != null)
            {
                source.IsEnabled = context.CanExecute();
            }
            // Added these 3 lines to get the effect you want
            else if (context.Target == null)
            {
                source.IsEnabled = false;
            }
            // EDIT: Bugfix - need this to ensure the button is activated if it has a target but no guard
            else 
            {
                source.IsEnabled = true;
            }

            return source.IsEnabled;
        };
```

This seems to work for me - there is no target for methods which couldn't be bound to a command, so in that case I just set `IsEnabled` to false. This activates buttons only when a method with a matching signature is found on the active child VM - obviously give it a good test before you use it :)

Comment: Hmm think that's not quite right, I'm having to supply a CanXX guard for it to work - having another look...

Comment: Ok I tweaked, just needed to make sure the button isn't *left alone* when a target is found but there is no CanXX guard (instead it's assumed that you want buttons that have no guard but have a handler to be enabled)

Answer (score 0):

Create methods and accompanying boolean properties for each of your commands on your shell view model. (See code below for an example.) Caliburn.Micro's conventions will wire them up to the buttons for you automatically. Then simply raise property changed events for the boolean properties when you change views to have them be re-evaluated.

For example, let's say you have a Save button. The name of that button in your xaml would be Save, and in your view model, you would have a Save method along with a CanSave boolean property. See below:

```
public void Save()
{
    var viewModelWithSave = ActiveItem as ISave;
    if (viewModelWithSave != null) viewModelWithSave.Save();
}

public bool CanSave { get { return ActivateItem is ISave; } }
```

Then, in your conductor, whenever you change your active screen, you would call `NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanSave);`. Doing this will cause your button to be disabled or enabled depending upon if the active screen is capable of dealing with that command. In this example, if the active screen doesn't implement `ISave`, then the Save button would be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Caliburn.Micro event aggregation in this scenario, as follows:

- Create a class named `ScreenCapabilities` with a bunch of Boolean attributes (e.g. `CanSave`, `CanLoad`, etc.)
- Create a message named `ScreenActivatedMessage` with a property of type `ScreenCapabilities`
- Create a view model for your ribbon that subscribes to (handles) the `ScreenActivatedMessage`

In the ribbon view model's `Handle` method, set the local CanXXX properties based on the supplied `ScreenCapabilities`.

It would look something like this (code typed by hand, not tested):

```cs
public class ScreenCapabilities
{
  public bool CanSave { get; set; }
  // ...
}

public class ScreenActivatedMessage
{
  public ScreenCapabilities ScreenCapabilities { get; set; }
  // ...
}

public class RibbonViewModel : PropertyChangedBase, IHandle<ScreenActivatedMessage>
{
  private bool _canSave;
  public bool CanSave
  {
    get { return _canSave; }
    set { _canSave = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(() => CanSave); }
  }

  // ...

  public void Handle(ScreenActivatedMessage message)
  {
    CanSave = message.ScreenCapabilities.CanSave;
    // ...
  }
}
```

Then, somewhere appropriate, when the screen changes, publish the message. See [see Caliburn.Micro wiki](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=The%20Event%20Aggregator) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Define a property (let's say ActiveScreen) for the active screen in the shell view model.
And let's assume you have properties for the each button such as DeleteButton, AddButton. 
Screen is a viewmodel for the screens.

```cs
    private Screen activeScreen;

    public Screen ActiveScreen
    {
        get
        {
            return activeScreen;
        }
        set
        {
            activeScreen= value;

            if (activeScreen.Name.equals("Screen1"))
            {
                 this.AddButton.IsEnabled = true; 
                 this.DeleteButton.IsEnabled = false; 
            }
            if else (activeScreen.Name.equals("Screen2"))
            {
                 this.AddButton.IsEnabled = true; 
                 this.DeleteButton.IsEnabled = true; 
            }

            NotifyPropertyChanged("ActiveScreen");
        }
    }
```